# Is there any overhead with this subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, explain

I wonder if this query has an overhead when I introduce a subquery:

```
SELECT p.id_product
FROM product p
JOIN reservation_product rp ON (p.id_product = rp.id_product)
JOIN reservation r ON (rp.id_reservation = r.id_reservation)

WHERE r.id_company =
-- **Subquery in question**
(SELECT r_inn.id_company FROM reservation r_inn WHERE r_inn.id_reservation = 56)

AND r.status = 'active'
-- Floor
AND r.checkout > '2012-05-30 13:00:00'
-- Ceil
AND r.checkin < '2012-05-30 15:00:00'
AND r.id_reservation <> 56
AND r.release_time IS NULL
```

I can require the user to set directly the id for the company and have a WHERE like this:

```
WHERE r.id_company = 1
```

I'm trying to avoid this with the introduction of the subquery like I showed in the first example, but I'm worried about a performance overhead.

This is the EXPLAIN (help me please with this, I don't get it the EXPLAIN clause yet) for the first query:

[image: EXPLAIN for the subquery query]

And the EXPLAIN for the harcoded one:

[image]

Comment: generally you need to be able to *read* the explain output to use it ;o)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kRHgz.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVQMH.png